'Bypassing' @SQLRestriction on entities for JPA queries
Background
I'm implementing both soft and hard delete functionality in a JPA/Hibernate application. Given an entity with SQLRestriction defined to restrict every query within the JPA to return non soft-deleted data:
@Entity
@SQLRestriction("deleted = false")
public class Product extends Auditables {

    @Id
    @SnowFlakeIdValue(name = "product_id")
    @Column(name = "product_id", columnDefinition = "BIGINT", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @Column(name = "deleted", nullable = false)
    private boolean deleted = false;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Variant> variants = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<ProductImage> images = new HashSet<>();
}


Note that @SQLRestrictions are always applied and cannot be disabled. Nor may they be parameterized. They're therefore much less flexible than filters.

Does this effectively mean we can't select data with restriction condition met? I need to query and manage both non-deleted AND soft-deleted records in specific cases (e.g., for hard deletion), but @SQLRestriction is always applied and cannot be disabled or parameterized according to the Hibernate documentation.
Additional Information
As how the soft delete works, rather than using @SoftDelete, I update the deleted field of the corresponding request's product.
Tried Approaches
As I wanted to be able to both soft-delete and hard-delete, I have tried various ways while still using @SQLRestriction, one of them was:
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT p FROM Product p")
    @SQLRestriction("")
    List<Product> findAllUnfiltered();

    @Modifying @Transactional
    @Query("DELETE FROM Product p WHERE p.productId = :productId AND p.deleted IN (true, false)")
    void deleteProductPermanently(@Param("productId") Long id);

    @Modifying @Transactional
    @Query("DELETE FROM Product p WHERE p.deleted IN (true, false)")
    void deleteAllProductsPermanently();
}

None of these attempts successfully bypass the @SQLRestriction.
Problem and Questions
Is there a way to bypass @SQLRestriction when needed while keeping its automatic filtering for regular queries? If not, what's the recommended approach?

Switch to Hibernate Filters?
Use EntityManager directly?
Write native SQL queries?
Other alternatives?

Environment
Spring Boot Framework: 3.3.4
Hibernate (.orm, core): 6.5.3 Final

Apparently it's not possible using SQLRestriction.
For your case @Filter & @FilterDef seem to be the way to go wich you can disable using the entity manager.
There is an article describing the exact use case. To access soft deleted data for e.g administrative purposes.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-soft-delete
